# Unable to run shell script from php code

Tags: php, bash

I have a shell script(i.e `mat.sh`) in `/var/www/` and also have a php script(i.e. `n1.php`) in the same directory. When i am running the shell script from bash command it is running, but when i m executing the same from the apache2 php server it is not executing.

`mat.sh` contains..

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF | /var/www/matlab  -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay /> result.out
a=add(2,3);
disp('this is done');
disp(a);
exit
EOF
```

note:`/var/www/matlab`is the directory of matlab link

`n1.php` contains..

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
if ($_GET['run'])
{
  # This code will run if ?run=true is set.
 echo "Execution starts here...<br/>\n";
 echo exec("whoami");
 echo "<br/>\n";
exec ("chmod a+x mat.sh", $output, $return);
if ($return != 0)

{
        //An error occured, fallback or whatever

        echo "Execution failed<br/>\n";
}
exec ("sh mat.sh");
}
?>

<!-- This link will add ?run=true to your URL, myfilename.php?run=true -->
<a href="?run=true">Click Me!</a>
```

Please help me.....

Comment: Try `shell_exec ("mat.sh");`

Comment: Sorry it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Do you get your error message when having done `chmod`?

Make sure that `mat.sh` has the same owner as your apache2-server-instance otherwise this line

```
exec ("chmod a+x mat.sh", $output, $return);
```

will fail, because only the owner can change permissions.

Comment: how to know the owner. And how to change the owner permission.